# Is there a way to force sitecore users to upload media as file?

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-media-library

Just as the title says, I need a way to force users to only upload media as file. From what I've seen the only way to upload as file is to upload using the advanced upload options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Media.UploadAsFiles` setting to force Sitecore to store all media items as files:

```xml
<!--
  UPLOAD AS FILES
    Controls whether Sitecore stores media as files or as database records by default.
    This setting is ignored if the Media.DisableFileMedia setting is true.
    Default: false

-->
<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="false"/>
```

Comment: I have made this change, but when a user selects upload file and uploads it, the file goes to the sitecore media library. The only way the user is able to upload as file is using the advanced options. Is there another setting I may have to change?

I've editited
<setting name="Media.UploadAsFiles" value="true"/>
as well as
<setting name="Media.FileFolder" value="/App_Data/MediaFiles" />

Comment: That should be the only config required. Unless you have `Media.DisableFileMedia` set to true. Have you checked `sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` if there is no config which overrides your settings?